# Setting up Pi headless

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I do not have a monitor for Pi. I am using just my laptop to connect to Pi. I've tried a lot of things as shown on the Internet but to no avail. I cannot find the IP of the Pi. I can't even figure out if it's working properly. Please help!
Pi 3
Laptop : Windows and Kali Dual boot
16GB SD Card

**EDIT 1** I do not have a router to which I can login. I am on a college LAN and can use Ethernet/WiFi for connections.

Comment: raspberry pi isn't a plug and play thing , u need to set it up with a screen for the first time (it'll probably take about 10min), use a friend screen(any screen that supports HDMI would do). once its done it'll work

Comment: ps if you want to find out pi's IP. you can simply use [nmap](https://nmap.org/)

Comment: @nafas If I setup it for the first time using screen keyboard etc, how would I ensure that I can access it afterwards without screen over my LAN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

Comment: Dmitry no, not a duplicate.

Comment: @SamFischer Well, there's no evidence in your question that you have tried anything from that list, and *I cannot find the IP of the Pi* gives no idea of what could be wrong. Perhaps you should describe your problem better instead of just stating that it's different.

Comment: @SamFischer there are steps you need to consider mate, most important this is to open the ssh . once you have done that having static ip make ur life easier (again if you don't have it, you have to find it everytime for example using nmap). I have a raspberry pi an set it up for 2 years and still running with no problem (same as you I don't have a monitor to always connected it to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got my solution. My network infrastructure is using switches so I couldn't login anywhere. What I did was : "nmap -sP 10.100.*.*/24" with *.* depending on probable IP range assigned on my building. 
I was successful in getting the RaspberryPi as manufacturers for on of the IPs. Then I simply SSHed in and am using the Pi smoothly.
Although, I had to create an empty file named 'ssh' in the boot partition of the SD card while using Raspbian Jessie with Pixel. Raspbian Lite does not need any such thing.

Thanks for all the kind responses.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things you can try.

**Option 1: enable SSH**
Plug SD card into reader and into your laptop. You will see the `/boot` partition. Create an empty file SSH here without file extension. This will enable SSH on boot. With some luck, you can already ssh into your raspi with default password

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

**Option 2: turn your rapsi to Ethernet Gadget and connect via USB cable**
https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget

In short:

1. plug SD card into reader and reader into your computer
2. edit in boot partition the following with a text editor:
   2.1. `config.txt` --> Go to the bottom and add `dtoverlay=dwc2` as the last line
   2.2. `cmdline.txt` --> After rootwait (the last word on the first line) add a space and then `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` be careful with spaces etc.
   2.3. with new Jessie you will need to create in /boot and empty file with the name `SSH` (no file extension!), this switches SSH by default on
3. if you are on a mac (OSX) you are fine, with Windows you probably need to install *Bonjour zeroconf* service (go to https://support.apple.com and search for *bonjour download*)
4. plug the usb cable into the USB jack marked "USB" (not "Power In") and plug it into your computer
5. Here you should be able to ping raspberrypi.local
6. if this works you can connect to your raspi with `pi@raspberrypi.local` initial password is `raspberry`
7. from here you can setup your raspi for Wifi etc.

**Option 3: Connect via console cable**
Get a console cable, connect it to the raspi, if you are on a Windows machine connect to it with Putty. You have to install a driver first. I bought a cheap USB zu TTL-Converter which kind of works most of the time but is very buggy. Try to get the cable from adafruit ~9USD, I believe it's working fine. Search for tutorials on how to use this on their site.
[USB to TTL Serial Cable - Debug / Console Cable for Raspberry Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/products/954)

Answer (score 2):

Does your laptop have an ethernet port or do you have a USB/ethernet adapter? If so just plug the pi right in with any regular ethernet cable and run `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` the password is `raspberry` This is more likely to work in linux, it relies on bonjour.

If you have an FTDI cable it's also possible to turn on the UART (`enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`) which provides a debug serial connection on pins 8 and 10 (http://pinout.xyz/pinout/uart)

Another option is to use a pi zero and configure it as an ethernet gadget (https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a) which doesn't require anything beyond the board, sdcard, and a usb cable.

Comment: If using a recent raspbian image SSH needs to be enabled for the first option to work, just create an empty file named `ssh` on the SD card. Be sure there's not a hidden file extension.

Comment: Just to expand on +plastic chris' point, creating */boot/ssh* enables ssh for a single boot. If you want ssh to be available persistently using the latest Raspbian jessie image, you need to enable the service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the SD card created with an OS image. Here is how to you find out the IP of your Raspberry Pi. 
1) Connect the raspberry Pi to your router via ethernet;
2) Login to your router and check on connected devices which is typically under DHCP section, Raspberry Pi always has a MAC address started as e8:4e:xx:xx:xx:xx, find the IP address that has a MAC address that match a Raspberry Pi;
3) You can then using SSH command (ssh pi@192.168.xxx.xxx) to connect to Raspberry Pi without a monitor and keyboard. If you are on Window, you probably need to download and install Putty in order to remotely access Raspberry Pi using SSH.

Comment: I do not have a router. I am on a college LAN and can use Ethernet / WiFi for connections.

Comment: In that case, can you run Terminal command? run command 'arp -a' would provide a list of IPs and MAC addresses connected to the network, if the Raspberry Pi is running and connected to the Ethernet, its IP and MAC address should be there.

Comment: Yes I can, actually I did setup up a Pi 2 last year with a Windows 7 machine headless by directly connecting it via ethernet. By it broke and I bought a new Pi just few days back and now I have no clue what to do :/

Comment: If you still can't see your Pi's IP using "arp -a', then you may want to create a new SD card and try again.

Comment: For Windows if nmap doesn't fit your ideal you can google something called "The Dude" it visually maps your immediate network.

Answer (score 0):

One way I locate IP numbers of different devices in networks is fing https://www.fing.io/# . It is available for iOS, Android, Windows, Linux etc, and it will scan the network for devices. You will get MAC addresses with the IP address and more. You can usually from deduct wich IP address goes to your pi. I get Raspberry Pi as manufacturer in the list for my Pis when I scan.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Pi has an OS image on the SD card already and you have an ethernet cable to connect your laptop to the pi, you can try this:

1. Put the memory card into the Pi and connect the pi to laptop via usb - when the green light stops blinking the OS should be installed
2. On your laptop, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`
3. Plug in the ethernet cable to the Pi and your laptop
4. Connect WiFi on laptop
5. Click WiFi icon > edit connections
6. Select ethernet (not WiFi!) > ipv4 settings
7. Change method to "shared to other computers"
8. Disconnect and reconnect WiFi
9. Search for the IP of the Pi by running 
   `sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet`. You should see the IP address for the pi. (Note, if nothing comes up under eth0, you can run `ifconfig` to see if you are using eth0 or something else and amend the command accordingly)
10. SSH into the Pi using the IP address, for example: `ssh pi@10.42.0.99`. The password should be raspberry by default